# An instance 0xa9923e0 of class myClass was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, observers

I have a class the uses an observer. 
The code is added on awakeFromNib

```
[self.contactSearchView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedContactUUID" options:0 context:nil];
self.contactSearchView.contactSelected = self.attendeeSelected;
```

On dealloc
The following code executed:

```
[self.contactSearchView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedContactUUID"];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

However, if I close an open that particular view many times eventually I generate the following exception and the app crashes.

An instance 0xa9923e0 of class MyClass was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:

Shortly after that the app crashes and I am not sure how to move forward.

Comment: Did you try to print self.contactSearchView in dealloc? Maybe it is already "nil" and you can't remove observer.

Comment: I did not try that let me give that a go thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If self adds itself as an observer to another object, then it must remove itself as an observer. At the very latest, you can do that in self's dealloc method.

Comment: This is the correct answer, perhaps @CodeMilian would be kind enough to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

to remove the observer:
[timer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timeText"];

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?